# MYSQL-Query with PHP in Chartjs

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, chart.js

I have a problem. I am on the way to make a chart using "ChartJS". Data is from a MYSQL Database and the labels too.

There is no problem with getting the data in my code, but with the labels. Can anyone find the mistake, why it does not work?

```
<script>
    var randomScalingFactor = function () {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
    };
    var lineChartData = {
        labels: [<?php foreach ($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM wetterdaten WHERE datum = '$datum'") as $row) {
            $uhrzeit = $row['uhrzeit'];
            echo "&quot;" . $uhrzeit . "&quot;, ";
        } ?>],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [<?php foreach ($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM wetterdaten WHERE datum = '$datum'") as $row) {
                    $luftfeuchtigkeit = $row['luftfeuchtigkeit'];
                    echo $luftfeuchtigkeit . ",";
                } ?>]
            }

        ]
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });
    }
</script>
```

In "Labels" there is the mistake, because, when I write the time manually like :

```
labels : ["13:05","14:01"],
```

it works fine! But it does not work with the MySQL-Statement.

Comment: Try using echo "'".$uhrzeit."'"; in place of echo "&quot;".$uhrzeit."&quot;, ";

Comment: Thank you very much! This works. @PrashantSharma